# If you want to develop a voice assistant, which language would you use?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, text-to-speech, voice, assistant

I am trying to develop a voice assistant, but I am confused on which language to use.
I want the app to work properly on both windows and android.
If you have any suggestions please post them.

Answer (score 2):

Python would be the best answer. Python has a lot of tools that you can use for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Definitly python. it has readily available lots of tools and libraries for us. For these type of projects i highly recommend python. Here are some tools and libraries might help you.

wikipedia - Get information from wikipedia or to perform wikipedia search

```
pip install wikipedia
```

Request - Making GET and POST requests.

```
pip install requests
```

Beautifulsoup4 - A library that makes it easy to scrape information from web pages.

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Pyttsx3 - Used for conversion of text to speech in a program it woks offline.

```
pip install pyttsx3
```

Wolframalpha - Compute expert-level answers using Wolfram's algorithms, knowledgebase and AI technology.

```
pip install wolframaplha
```

Subprocess - Getting system subprocess details which are used in various commands. for example, Sleep, Shutdown etc. This module comes built-in with python.

Web browser - To perform web search. built-in with python

Twilio - For making call and messages.

```
pip install twilio
```

Tkinter - For building GUI. Comes built-in with python.

Hope you will find this information helpful.